# Unable to run Spring Boot app after upgrading to 2.2.4: method does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, resttemplate

I got an error after upgrading Spring Boot version from 2.1.11 to 2.2.4. Then I upgraded spring-cloud-starter-openfeign from 2.0.2 to 2.2.1, but it didn't help.

The following method did not exist:

```
'org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(int)'
```

The method's class, org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/a/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.2.4.RELEASE/225a4fd31156c254e3bb92adb42ee8c6de812714/spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/a/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.2.4.RELEASE/225a4fd31156c254e3bb92adb42ee8c6de812714/spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

The attempt to call the method occurs in a custom class's constructor

```
 this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(props.getConnectTimeoutMs()).setReadTimeout(props.getReadTimeoutMs()).build();
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE")
        classpath('gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:0.17.2')
        classpath('org.unbroken-dome.gradle-plugins:gradle-testsets-plugin:2.2.1')
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.2"
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.6.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'
apply plugin: 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets'

sourceCompatibility = 11

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.RELEASE'
    }
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic'
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-core'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:2.2.1.RELEASE')
    compile('io.github.openfeign:feign-jackson:10.7.4')
    compile("org.togglz:togglz-spring-boot-starter:2.6.1.Final")
    compile('org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE')
    runtime('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.3.2')
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6")
    compile("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Final")
    annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final")
    compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus:1.2.12')
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2")
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2')
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.10.2")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.2")
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7')
    compile('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.8')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
    testCompile('org.testcontainers:spock:1.12.4')
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5")
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.3-groovy-2.5")
    testCompile('nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:3.1.10')
    compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure:1.20.1')
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6")
    testCompile('com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.15.0')
    testCompile('com.github.tomjankes:wiremock-groovy:0.2.0')
    testCompile('com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.2.0')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Javadoc for versions [2.1.11](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.11.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html#setConnectTimeout-int-) and [2.2.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html#setConnectTimeout-java.time.Duration-) respectively.  The older version still exposes this method taking an `int` argument but already states that it's deprecated and that you should use `java.time.Duration` instead.

The method accepting `java.time.Duration` still exists in 2.2.4 and you should use that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `setConnectTimeout(int connectTimeout)`  has been deprecated and instead  `setConnectTimeout(Duration connectTimeout)` has been added.Please try to add this

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It solves my problem just as the previous answer by wjans

Comment: Please up-vote if you feel it helps.Almost both answered at same time

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation :(